# How to enforce a URL to be visited before another?

Tags: javascript, url, web-applications

I have two URLs, `A` and `B`. I want to prevent users from directly accessing `B`, and would like to enforce a 'rule' such that one can only access `B` **after** visiting `A`. More specifically, the only route to land on `B` is via a redirect on `A`.

I was thinking to use some js in `B` to check `document.referrer`, if it is not `A` then redirect the user out of `B`. However, this may not work in my case as `B` is reached *using a redirect*, in which case `document.referrer` would not give me `A`.

I would also prefer, if possible, *not to* have to do the check using js *after the content of `B` is loaded*, which would help saving some bandwidth.

Is there any effective and robust method for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have page A set a cookie, and page B check for the existance of the cookie. It is not foolproof nor 100% robust, but it is the accepted method for enforcing such restrictions in stateless applications such as the web.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the loading the content of B when A has not been viewed yet, then your server needs to set a cookie when the viewer views A and when your server is asked for B, it needs to check for the existence of the proper cookie and NOT serve up the B page contents unless the desired cookie from A is present.  You don't describe what you want to happen if the user goes to B when they haven't yet been to A, but your server could set a redirect to A or could serve up a message that the user hasn't done things in the correct order and give them a link to click on.

Conceptually, this is sort of like requiring a viewer login on page A before you will allow the viewing of page B.  The login (setting of the cookie) can be automatic after viewing page A or you can require the viewer to take some action on page A (provide credentials, click a button, etc...) before the cookie is set that allows access to page B.